# Rotativa pdf generte issue after calling Action from another controller

Tags: pdf-generation, rotativa, controllercontext

Getting errro at ControllerContext after  calling Action from another controller:-

```
 var pdfBytes = new ViewAsPdf("MonthlyReport", GetOverAllSales)
            {
                PageWidth = 215.9,
                PageHeight = 279.4,
                PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(4, 6, 4, 4)
            }.BuildFile(ControllerContext);
            var fileName = "MonthlySalesReport_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf";
```